# Cufon.js работает не для всех элементов

Tags: javascript, шрифты

Использую на сайте cufon.js, чтобы определённые элементы (заголовки и т.п.) были написаны красивым шрифтом. Чтобы скрипт отличал, что именно надо обрабатывать, всем этим элементам присвоен `class="fontName"` и Cufon вызван через `Cufon.replace(".fontName")`

Поначалу всё шло прекрасно, заголовки и прочие элементы отображались нужным шрифтом. Но начиная с какого-то момента присваивание этого класса перестало оказывать эффект: в коде для элемента указан всё тот же `class="fontName"`, но элемент отображается шрифтом по умолчанию. При этом те элементы, которые отображались правильно с самого начала, по-прежнему отображаются нужным мне шрифтом. Сами теги при этом одни и те же (например, `td` и в том, и в другом случае).

В чём может быть проблема и как это исправить?

**UPD:** Уточняю по итогам первых коммнтариев: ни аякса, ни onload, ни смены стилей «на лету», ни ещё какой-то экзотики не используется.

Всё, что используется:

1) Подключение Cufon:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/FontName.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Cufon.replace(".fontName");
</script>
```

2) Указание для нужных элементов класса `fontName`. Например:

```
<td class="fontName">
Этот текст должен выводиться красивым шрифтом
</td>
```

Класс указывается непосредственно в шаблоне, ответственном за вывод соответствующего фрагмента страницы, т.е. при первой загрузке страницы он уже присутствует в html-коде.

3) после вывода всех элементов, где должен быть этот шрифт, вызывается `Cufon.now()` для ускорения отрисовки. Пробовал убрать — не влияет.

При этом одни элементы, для которых задан `class="fontName"`, выводятся нужным шрифтом, а другие, для которых точно так же задан этот класс — шрифтом по умолчанию.

**UPD 2:** Проблема решена: дело было всё-таки в `Cufon.now()`. Эта функция вызывалась два раза, и не обрабатывались элементы, которые стояли в коде после первого вызова. Когда я убрал этот первый вызов и оставил только последний, всё заработало.

Comment: сбросить кэш?

Comment: Кэш ни при чём: при просмотре исходного кода видно, что нужный class стоит где положено. Впрочем, пробовал и сбрасывать — не помогает.

Comment: Случайно они не аяксом подгружаются?

Answer (score 1):

присваивание этого класса перестало оказывать эффект. Я так понимаю вы делаете что-то типа:

```
onload = function() {
   var els = document.getElementsByClassName("class");
   for( var i=0, l=els.length; i<l; ++i ) {
       // и тут меняете стили
   }
}
```

И где-то, по какой-то причине создаете элемент

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.className = "class";
```

Если так - то естественно работать это не будет, не трудно понять почему. Вы задаете стили для существующих элементов, но не для тех, который будут созданы позже.

Если же проблема в чем-то другом - опишите ее по человечески, сейчас ваш вопрос можно смело размещать на форум программистов экстрасенсов.